# The table does not appear in the middle of page despite using \centering command

Tags: latex, tabular

I have generated a table for the experimental results part of my manuscript in the LaTeX environment and it is working in my personal file but when I copy it into a Springer Journal LaTeX template file the table does not appear in the middle of the page and it goes outside the page margins. Its size is not that much large and I don't think that it does not fit on the page.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable,verbatim}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{sidewaystable}[ph!]
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{Comparison of the performances of the LNS approach and MIP formulation on small-size instances}
\begin{tabular}{|c||cc|c|c|cc|cc|cc|cc|}
\hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Instance}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{OBJ} & Gap (\%) & Diff (\%) & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ CPU(s)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$C_{max}$(h)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$C_{avg}$(h)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$TD$(km)}\\ 
& MIP & LNS  &  MIP & LNS & MIP & LNS &  MIP & LNS &  MIP & LNS &  MIP & LNS\\ 
\hline
\hline
L-M01R02S3 & *** & *** &  0 &  0 & $<1$ & 2 & 1.81 & 1.81 & 1.17 & 1.17 & 51.7 &  51.7\\
L-M01R02S4 & *** & *** & 0 &  0 &$<1$ & 2 &  2.1 &  2.1 & 1.25  & 1.25 & 71.8 &  71.8 \\
L-M01R02S5 & *** & *** & 0 & 0 &$<1$ & 2 &  2.46 & 2.46 & 1.22 & 1.22 & 70.7 & 70.7\\
L-M01R02S6 & *** & *** & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 &  2.96 & 2.96 & 1.19 & 1.19 & 68.7 & 68.7\\
L-M02R02S6 & *** & ***  & 0 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 1.73 & 1.73 & 0.94 & 0.94 & 67.1 & 67.1 \\
L-M02R02S7 & *** & *** & 0 &  0 & 20 & 5 & 1.71  & 1.71 & 0.67 & 0.67 & 69.2 & 69.2\\
L-M02R02S8 & *** & *** &  0 &  0 & 182 & 5 & 1.7 & 1.7 & 0.77 & 0.77 & 75 & 75\\
L-M02R02S9 & *** & *** & 28.45 &  0 & 1800 & 101 &  2.72 & 2.72 &  1.32 & 1.32 & 120 & 120\\
L-M02R02S10 & *** & *** & 40.49 &  0 & 1800 & 102 & 2.99 & 2.99 & 1.38 & 1.38 & 129.6 & 129.6\\
L-M02R02S11 & *** & *** & 50 & -0.1  & 1800 & 113 & 2.67 & 2.67  & 1.22 & 1.22 & 110 & 110 \\
L-M02R02S12 & *** & *** & 58.49 & -1.83 & 1800 & 124 & 2.8 & 2.4 & 1.11 & 1.09 & 156 & 164.2\\
M-M04R02S27 & *** & *** & * & -27.75 & 1800 & 139 & 2.97 & 2.96 & 1.52 & 1.19 & 274.8 & 226.7\\
M-M08R02S36 & *** & *** & * & -34.59 & 1800 & 166 & 2.99 & 2.78 & 1.17 & 1.05 & 475.2 & 399.6\\
M-M12R02S46 & *** & *** & * & -71.86 & 1800 & 124 & 2.93 & 1.73 & 1.68 & 0.62 & 737.7 & 323.4\\
H-M16R02S59 & *** & *** & * & -69.98 & 1800 & 145 & 2.96 & 1.98 & 1.6 & 0.77 & 752.7 & 560.2\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{SAvsM}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

It seems the related journal does not support the sidewaystable command. Does anyone know what is the problem? I appreciate your time.

Comment: Looks pretty much centred to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdr6M.png

Comment: Yes but as I said when I copy it to a journal source file I face the problem and I don't understand what is the reason.

Comment: Then you should make a [mre] that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: actually, the document class is \documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3},here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-general-template-file-for-the-latex-package-svjour3-for-springer-journals/pbbwqhxxvtbp . You can copy my code here and compile it and see what is the problem. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/363799/36296 You should edit your question here to actually reproduce the problem. In its current state, it is just misleading.

Answer (score 1):

`sidewaystable` does not seem to work for the class of that journal. I think you may need to consult with their support.

There is a way to *simulate* the environment but I would be careful with such workarounds, if it's already break something that should work! It's always best to double check the code will be accepted.

Anyway here's a way of rendering your table with `rotatebox`. Unfortunately, `caption` cannot be rotated so I had to simulate it.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable,verbatim}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{blue}}


\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\clearpage
\vspace*{0pt plus 1fil}
\bgroup
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \refstepcounter{table}%
  \label{SAvsM}
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
    {Table~\thetable. Comparison of the performances of the LNS approach and MIP formulation on small-size instances}
  }%
  \hspace{6pt}
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c||cc|c|c|cc|cc|cc|cc|}
      \hline
      \hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{Instance}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{OBJ}
      & Gap (\%) & Diff (\%)
      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ CPU(s)}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$C_{max}$(h)}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$C_{avg}$(h)}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$TD$(km)}\\ 
      & MIP & LNS  &  MIP & LNS & MIP & LNS &  MIP & LNS &  MIP & LNS &  MIP & LNS\\ 
      \hline
      \hline
      L-M01R02S3 & *** & *** &  0 &  0 & $<1$ & 2 & 1.81 & 1.81 & 1.17 & 1.17 & 51.7 &  51.7\\
      L-M01R02S4 & *** & *** & 0 &  0 &$<1$ & 2 &  2.1 &  2.1 & 1.25  & 1.25 & 71.8 &  71.8 \\
      L-M01R02S5 & *** & *** & 0 & 0 &$<1$ & 2 &  2.46 & 2.46 & 1.22 & 1.22 & 70.7 & 70.7\\
      L-M01R02S6 & *** & *** & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 &  2.96 & 2.96 & 1.19 & 1.19 & 68.7 & 68.7\\
      L-M02R02S6 & *** & ***  & 0 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 1.73 & 1.73 & 0.94 & 0.94 & 67.1 & 67.1 \\
      L-M02R02S7 & *** & *** & 0 &  0 & 20 & 5 & 1.71  & 1.71 & 0.67 & 0.67 & 69.2 & 69.2\\
      L-M02R02S8 & *** & *** &  0 &  0 & 182 & 5 & 1.7 & 1.7 & 0.77 & 0.77 & 75 & 75\\
      L-M02R02S9 & *** & *** & 28.45 &  0 & 1800 & 101 &  2.72 & 2.72 &  1.32 & 1.32 & 120 & 120\\
      L-M02R02S10 & *** & *** & 40.49 &  0 & 1800 & 102 & 2.99 & 2.99 & 1.38 & 1.38 & 129.6 & 129.6\\
      L-M02R02S11 & *** & *** & 50 & -0.1  & 1800 & 113 & 2.67 & 2.67  & 1.22 & 1.22 & 110 & 110 \\
      L-M02R02S12 & *** & *** & 58.49 & -1.83 & 1800 & 124 & 2.8 & 2.4 & 1.11 & 1.09 & 156 & 164.2\\
      M-M04R02S27 & *** & *** & * & -27.75 & 1800 & 139 & 2.97 & 2.96 & 1.52 & 1.19 & 274.8 & 226.7\\
      M-M08R02S36 & *** & *** & * & -34.59 & 1800 & 166 & 2.99 & 2.78 & 1.17 & 1.05 & 475.2 & 399.6\\
      M-M12R02S46 & *** & *** & * & -71.86 & 1800 & 124 & 2.93 & 1.73 & 1.68 & 0.62 & 737.7 & 323.4\\
      H-M16R02S59 & *** & *** & * & -69.98 & 1800 & 145 & 2.96 & 1.98 & 1.6 & 0.77 & 752.7 & 560.2\\
      \hline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}}
  \par
\egroup
\vspace{0pt plus 1fil}

\end{document}
```